# No se me Visualiza las alertas

Tags: php, pdo, materialize, alert

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de visualizar las alertas, resulta he separado en tres partes el código el primero es `marca.php` que es donde se visualiza todo el contenido, el segundo `ventana_modal_agregar_marca.php` que es donde se carga el formulario para ingresar los datos a registrar u el ultimo archivo es `config_agregar_marca.php` tambien estan los de modificar y eliminar que su llamado se hace por medio de ventana modal el gran problema que tengo es que no se me visualiza las alertas en marca.php agradeceria su ayuda.

**marca.php**

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>MAR</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon/favicon.png">
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">

<!-- Contenedor de las alertas -->
<div id="alert-container"></div>

<!-- menu-->
<?php
include 'menu.php';
?>
<!-- fin menu-->

                  <br>
                         <br>



<!-- consultar registros -->
<div class="container">

<!-- boton para llamar a la ventana modal, excel y pdf-->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger btn-small" href="#agregar">
<img src='../icons/add.png' style="margin: -6px 2px;"> Añadir Registros</a>
<!-- fin boton para llamar a la ventana modal -->



    <div class="row">
    <div class="card" style="background-color: #ffa000;">
              <div class="card-tabs">
                <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width tabs-transparent">
                  <li class="tab"><a class="active">Listado General Marcas de Vehiculos</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

                     <div class="card-content white">
                     <div id="test1" class="center-align light">

<div class="row">
<input id="buscador" placeholder="FILTRAR REGISTROS">       
</div>

<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>N°</th>
              <th>ID-BD</th>
              <th>MARCA</th>
              <th>ACCIONES</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM marca ORDER BY id_marca;");
if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
$i=1;
 ?>

<?php
while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo "
        <tbody id='tabla'>
          <tr>
            <td>$i</td>";?>
            <td><?php echo $linea['id_marca']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linea['marca']; ?></td>           
<td>


<button data-target="#modificar_<?php echo $linea['id_marca']; ?>" 
class='btn modal-trigger btn waves-effect waves-light blue btn-small tooltipped' 
data-position='top' data-tooltip='Modificar'><img src='../icons/mode_edit.png' 
style="margin: 4px 2px;"></button>



<button data-target="#eliminar_<?php echo $linea['id_marca']; ?>" 
class='btn modal-trigger btn waves-effect waves-light red btn-small tooltipped' 
data-position='top' data-tooltip='Eliminar'><img src='../icons/delete.png' 
style="margin: 4px 2px;"></button>

</td>
</tr>
<!-- ventana modal-->

<?php
include "ventana_modal_modificar_marca.php";
include "ventana_modal_eliminar_marca.php";
?>

<!-- fin ventana modal-->
</tbody>

<?php

$i++;
}
}

else
echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !
</h5>
</div>";
echo "</table>";
?>


<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM marca");
$consulta->execute();
$marca = $consulta->rowCount();
?>
<h6 class="right-align black-text"><?php print("TOTAL REGISTROS EXISTENTES: 
<span class='red-text text-darken-2'><b>$marca\n</b></span>"); ?></h6>



                </div>
            </div>

<!--  fin Pie de pagina-->
<div class="col s12 center-align">
                  <label class="white-text">MAR</label>
           </div>
<!--  fin Pie de pagina-->
              </div>  
        </div> 
</div>

 <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script>

      <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      <?php if (isset($errMSG)): ?>
        M.toast({html: 'Error: <?php echo $errMSG; ?>', classes: 'grey darken-4'});
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (isset($successMSG)): ?>
        M.toast({html: '<?php echo $successMSG; ?>', classes: 'grey darken-4'});
      <?php endif; ?>
    });
  </script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  });
  </script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".modal").modal();
  });
  </script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
  });
</script>

<!-- FILTRO DE TABLA-->
<script>
   $("#buscador").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#tabla").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});
  </script>
<!-- FIN FILTRO DE TABLA-->


<!-- AGREGAR CATEGORIAS MODAL -->
<?php 
include 'ventana_modal_agregar_marca.php';
?>
<!-- FIN AGREGAR CATEGORIAS MODAL -->

</body>
</html>
```

**ventana_modal_agregar_marca.php**

```
<div id="agregar" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Agregar Marca de Vehículo</h4>
              <form class="col s12" action="config_agregar_marca.php" method="POST">
                <br>
                   <div class="row">
                           <div class="input-field col s12">
                               <input id='marca' class="black-text" type="text" name="marca" autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s]+" required>
                               <label for="marca">Marca</label>
                          </div>
                   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <a href="#!" class="modal-close btn waves-effect waves-light grey keychainify-checked">Cancelar</a>
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light teal" type="submit" name="agregar">Agregar</button>
    </div>
             </form>
</div>
<!-- FIN AGREGAR REGISTRO CON VENTANA MODAL -->
```

**config_agregar_marca.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
include "../conexion/conexion.php";
//$crud = new crud($DB_con);
?>

<!-- fin conexion y errores-->

<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
  $sql = "SELECT marca FROM marca WHERE marca = :marca LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $check->bindParam(':marca', $_POST['marca']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
  $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
  $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
  if ($contador > 0) {
  $check->closeCursor();
    
              $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !";



    }
    else
    {

$sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO marca (marca) VALUES (:marca)");
$sql->bindParam(':marca', $_POST['marca']);
$sql->execute();

          $successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";

          

        }
  }

header('location: marca.php');

?>
<!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```